# Sorting by days of week and time in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am setting up a registration tool for a group of courses. The courses have days (string), start_time (time), end_time (time). Also I am using Postgres in this project. An example of days is "M, W, F" but I can change if that would help.

I am looking to group the courses first by day, then by time, but without duplicates. What I mean is, if a class meets Monday/Wednesday/Friday I am fine displaying it just on Monday. We are doing this primarily to prevent people from signing up for a class at the same time.

If I have a model name Course, how can I display on the view in this way:

```
Monday:
CS1 | Intro to Programming | 10:00AM-11:00AM
CS2 | Intro to Java        | 10:00AM-11:00AM
CS4 | Databases            | 4:00PM-5:00PM

Tuesday:
CS3 | Intro to Web Dev     | 3:00PM-5:00PM
```

I am not sure if having the days as a string would be the best option but I am not sure what would be the correct way.

Course Model:

```
  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "code"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "professor"
    t.string   "cformat"
    t.string   "sections"
    t.integer  "credits"
    t.time     "start_time"
    t.time     "end_time"
    t.string   "days"
    t.integer  "max_cap"
  end
```

Comment: what are the attributes of course?

Comment: I've added it to the question, my initial thoughts are to create a hash or array and get them grouped in the controller so I can just loop through in view

Answer (score 1):

How is the day of the week being saved?

```
@monday_courses = Course.where(day_of_week: "Monday")
```

If you're saving something like "MWF" you could do something like this:

```
@monday_courses = Course.select {|course| course.day.include?("M")}
```

I'm sure that query could be optimized further by adding additional constraints (maybe only courses belonging to the school or whatever) but that's basically what you'd do.

Comment: The second suggestion is a solution based on how you're saving...just replace "M" with the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up doing. I think space wise it's not the most efficient but at least it is down to one ActiveRecord Query, it removes duplicates. Also having the Hash was helpful because in the view I was able to create the table but without duplicating the code for the table since it was in the loop and the day was the key, courses for that day were the value as an array

```
# Creating hash of classes
@monday_courses = Array.new
@tuesday_courses = Array.new
@wednesday_courses = Array.new
@thursday_courses = Array.new
@friday_courses = Array.new

Course.all.order("start_time ASC").each do |course|
    if course.days.include?("M")
        @monday_courses.push(course)
    elsif course.days.include?("T")
        @tuesday_courses.push(course)
    elsif course.days.include?("W")
        @wednesday_courses.push(course)
    elsif course.days.include?("R")
        @thursday_courses.push(course)
    elsif course.days.include?("F")
        @friday_courses.push(course)
    end
end

@courses_hash = Hash["Monday" => @monday_courses, "Tuesday" => @tuesday_courses, "Wednesday" => @wednesday_courses, "Thursday" => @thursday_courses, "Friday" => @friday_courses]
```